# Feat Interaction: Does the Magic in the Blood apply to Highborn Drow?

Tags: feats, dnd-3e, racial-traits

*Magic in the Blood*<sup>**1**</sup> turns your racial spell-like abilities from 1/day to 3/day. *Highborn Drow*<sup>**2**</sup> gives you additional spell-like abilities.

---

Would those spell-like abilities count as racial spell-like abilities, granted by one feat, for the purpose of being increased from 1/day to 3/day, by the other feat?

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>You can use your racial spell-like abilities more often than you otherwise could. Any ability that is otherwise usable 1/day is now usable 3/day.</sub> 

<sup>**2**</sup><sub>You may use detect good, detect magic, and levitate once per day as spell-like abilities with a caster level equal to your character level.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly, I would think not. The spells you gain from that feat are not listed in a racial description, and nothing indicates that they are racial abilities. (E.g. Nothing says they are added "in addition to any other racial spell-likes" or similar.)

The same interpretation ("no") is also implied (but not stated) in the flavor text, where Magic in the Blood refers to "innate abilities" (things you automatically have) and Highborn Drow refers to "unlocking" your heritage (something due to you, but not necessarily had).

That said, feats are expensive, this is a neat gimmick at very low levels only, and it shouldn't break anything if you house rule that it works.

---

As an aside, one might possibly argue that this was briefly okay, but no longer: Highborn Drow was a [racial] feat when Races of Faerun was printed, but was overridden by Underdark about six months later.

Comment: I fell like you could use ------------------ to add a separation line and include your comment as a note below the line, since comments are prone to deletion.